# Which layout to use to show conversations?

Tags: android

If I want to show messages in a threaded conversation, which layout should I use? A linear layout with text views or a list view? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i suggest you to go with ListView as the number of conservation increase in listview the customadapter i.e., android take care about show  few list item while scrolling.

if you use LinearLayout or any other layout then then you will run into problems as the number of conservation increases

Here is the [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom) for a sample example to implement

Comment: You say that if the number of conversations increases I will run into problems. What kind of problems?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a ListView with a ListAdapter or a CursorAdapter if reading from a database (more efficient), a useful post:
[Is there a super simple List / ListAdapter example out there for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688193/is-there-a-super-simple-list-listadapter-example-out-there-for-android)