# Android: how to get values from strings.xml into listview?

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

In my Android app I want to make a list of options that can be clicked. On whichever item you click, it always brings you to the same next screen but with a different .putextra(). I can do this with a simple ListAdapter as [is done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693630/1650012).

That works fine, but I do want the values to be translated in the app for different languages. I guess this means I need to define all the values in the listview in my strings.xml. I can of course define some values in strings.xml, but I wouldn't know where to start to get values from my strings.xml into a listview.

Does anybody know how I would be able to get translatable values into an Android ListView? Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. storing strings in `strings.xml` and make a list or array contains
   their ids. you can use what @TabrejKhan has said for this option.
2. Storing a string array as follows and pass it to your adapter.

Like:

```
<string-array name="my_string_list">
    <item>String 1</item>
    <item>String 2</item>
    <item>String 3</item>
    <item>String 4</item>
    <item>String 5</item>
</string-array>
```

And in your java code create the adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity,
                R.array.my_string_list);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Do you consider either one to be the better one? And if so, why?

Comment: I prefer second option, as you don't occupy extra space in your code and in R.java

Comment: The second, for sure!

Comment: Alright, so the second option it is. But where do I store this string array? In the fragment layout file, or somewhere else?

Comment: in same file strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is....
Create your array like this:

```
String[] listItems = {R.string.text1, R.string.text2, R.string.text3, R.string.text4 /*and so on*/ };
```

Comment: But, "R.string.text1" ..... are "int" items, how can you store them in a String Array. Can you explain?